# TensorFlow Custom Model Signatures for TFServing with DistributionLambda layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-probability

**Problem Context:**

I have a quite simple regression model with the first layer:
`feature_column.dense_features_v2.DenseFeatures` 
and the last layer:
`tfp.layers.DistributionLambda` TFProbability layer,

with the following structure:

[image: Mode Summary:]

Everything works well for the training and predictions of the distribution. Since I have distribution as the output of this model myinference needs to be done differently:

instead of calling:

`yhat = model.predict(input_data)`

I need to call:

`yhat = model(input_data)`
to get the distribution and then process the corresponding outputs I want:

`median = yhat.quantile(0.5).numpy().ravel()`

`stddev = yhat.stddev().numpy().ravel()`

This means that I have a non-standard inference procedure and the deployment using the TF-Serving does not give me the desired output.

**THE PROBLEM**

I would like to deploy my model using TensorFlow-Serving but I do not know how to get my custom outputs:

`{median, mean}` instead of `{'prediction':100}` from the standard TFServing `predict` method output.

I have found that I will probably need to modify my model's Signatures during the `save_model` step, since:

if I inspect them, I am getting:

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['feature_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: serving_default_id_brand:0
    inputs['feature_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: serving_default_id_category:0
        ...
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['output_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall_117:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

-> I have `output_1` only 1 output.

but I can't find any examples of how to do that in TensorFlow 2.

I have found some old implementations (working for TF1: https://sthalles.github.io/serving_tensorflow_models/), but can't figure out how should do it.

For now, I am stuck on how to properly define all this for several inputs (I need to somehow define a `tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction` ?) and my desired outputs.

My inputs are (it is an OrderedDict from Features vectors, so I think it is even more complex ...):

```
inputs = {
   'feature_1': <tf.Tensor 'feature_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int16>,
   'feature_2': <tf.Tensor 'feature_2:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int16>,
   ...
}
and I would like:

outputs = {
        "median": median,
        "stddev": stddev
   }
```

Any Help, tutorial etc would be appreciated!!!

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am also stuck with the same thing and can't find any solution online